# INSERT Statement not working Concrete5

Tags: php, mysql, concrete5

Im trying to insert some values into the DB inside a concrete5 single page and it's telling me that my syntax is wrong. I'm not sure where the syntax is wrong because i went by what was on their website.
My code is Below.

```
<?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
$db = Loader::db();
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$user = $_POST['userName'];
$costcenter = $_POST['costCenter'];
$index = 0;

foreach($quantity as $info){
$num = mysql_real_escape_string($quantity[$index]);
echo "$num";
echo "</br>";
$item = mysql_real_escape_string($product[$index]);
echo "$item";
echo "</br>";
$company = mysql_real_escape_string($vendor[$index]);
echo "$company";
echo "</br>";
$shipping = mysql_real_escape_string($address[$index]);
echo "$shipping";
echo "</br>";
$person = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
echo "$person";
echo "</br>";
$center = mysql_real_escape_string($costcenter);
echo "$center";
echo "</br>";

                $sql = "INSERT INTO Orders (quantity,orderItem,vendor,shippingAddress,userName,costCenter) VALUES $num,$item,$company,$shipping,$person,$center";
                $db->Execute($sql);


$index++;

    }   

?>
```

Comment: How about this syntax `INSERT INTO Orders (col1, col2) VALUES (value1, value2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your values in parenthesis

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Orders (quantity,orderItem,vendor,shippingAddress,userName,costCenter) VALUES ($num,$item,$company,$shipping,$person,$center)";
```

Comment: That didn't help im still getting the same error. If i replace the " with ' then it will insert but it doesn't instert the variable values it just insert the variable itself.

Comment: Then you'll have to escape each variable like VALUES ('".$variable."', etc)

Comment: This is how i escaped them and it did the same thing.

Comment: $sql = 'INSERT INTO Orders (quantity,orderItem,vendor,shippingAddress,userName,costCenter) VALUES (".$num.",".$item.",".$company.",".$shipping.",".$person.",".$center.")';
    $db->Execute($sql);

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Now im not getting an error it's just inputing the variable as opposed to its value.

Comment: Add the quotes like Machavity did in his answer.

Comment: Added that and it didn't change anything, it's still just inputing the variable as opposed to it's value.

Comment: Can you update your post with the new insert statement?  Are your echo statements printing out the correct values?

Comment: I went back and rearranged the quatations and it worked. Your resolution teeling me to esacape them did it. Thank you soo much man.

Comment: your answer has an unexpected quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis around the variables after values.
Example:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ("value1", "value2", "value3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two problems. First, your VALUES list needs to be wrapped by parenthesis. The second problem is your values aren't surrounded by quotes. So when your SQL is dumped out, you're putting strings directly into the list. You can get away with this if you're expecting a number but the strings will fail to insert.

```
$person = '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . '"';
```

Try adding that to your inputs and I bet it goes through.